# Vue & Vuex not retrieving proper value in html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a navbar where I only show certain menu items based off the user's role.

Here is the HTML (I removed all the menu items except one to simplify):

```
<v-speed-dial class="speed-dial-container contextual-text-menu" v-if="user && user.emailVerified" fixed top right
  direction="bottom" transition="slide-y-transition">
  
<v-icon v-if="checkAuthorization(['superAdmin', 'admin', 'pastor', 'member']) === true" class="mt-2"
    @click="sendComponent({ component: 'Dashboard' })">$admin</v-icon>
  
</v-speed-dial>
```

My method:

```
async checkAuthorization(permissions) {
  if (permissions.length > 0) {
    const temp = await this.$store.dispatch('UserData/isAuthorized', permissions)
    return temp
  }
},
```

Vuex store:

```
isAuthorized({
  state
}, permissions) {
  const userRoles = state.roles
  if (permissions && userRoles) {
    const found = userRoles.some(r => permissions.includes(r))
    return found
  }
},
```

All of my console logs show the correct values but the HTML is not responding accordingly.

Example: in this line of code `checkAuthorization(['superAdmin', 'admin', 'pastor', 'member']) === true` I added 'member' and I am logged in as a user that ONLY has the 'member' role. When looking through the console logs everything returns true so I should see this menu item but it does not show.

Comment: Your `checkAuthorization` is an async function so it always return Promise and Promise is not equal to true.

Comment: If I remove the async I get [object Promise] in the console

Comment: I removed the async and I get this in the console ```Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: true```

Comment: The problem is you cannot bind asynchronous function like that (and the Vuex dispatch function is asynchronous) so you have to create another variable e.g. `role` then set this variable after dispatch function resolve and call `checkAuthorization` in something like `created`/`mounted` hook.

Comment: @User28 I think this worked. put this in an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks, you can also answer your question, btw the answer from @Beyers is also interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone pointed out in the comments, `checkAuthorization` is an async function and will return a Promise, so you cannot check for `promise === true`.

That aside, I would change `isAuthorized` to be a vuex getter and not an action, e.g.

```
getters: {
  // ...
  isAuthorized: (state) => (permissions) => {
    if (permissions && state.roles) {
      return state.roles.some(r => permissions.includes(r))
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

And update `checkAuthorization` to not return a promise e.g.

```
function checkAuthorization(permissions) {
  if (permissions.length > 0) {
    return this.$store.getters.isAuthorized(permissions);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I am having difficulty testing your approach. my getters are this ```const getters = {``` not ```getters: {```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do :

I add another user state as `Unknown` and make it the default state.

In main main.js (or main.ts) I call state.initialize(), which determines user's state.

And, the key thing is to use navigation guards. Instead of checking routing guards on router-link (or url or anywhere in this step), you should define it in the router. There is a `router.beforeEach` function you can use, so that you can check if user is authorized to use that route, and redirect the user to 401 page if the user don't have permission.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: Thank you for answering, however, I do use route guards. In this situation I need to show or hide the menu item based off the user's role. In addition to this I have a route guard that will not let the user go to the route if they do not have authorization. My goal is to not even show the menu item if they are not authorized